# My iAP doesn't work on Wi-Fi connected to IPv6 network

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I did iAP for donation and request Apple for review. They rejected this because "when reviewed on the iPad running iOS 10.3.3 on Wi-Fi connected to an iPv6 the in-app purchases found in the app were unresponsive when being tapped." They attached a screen:

[image]

I did check this and it works on both: iPad and iPhone:

[image]
[image]

What may be the reason that it doesn't work on their iPad?

I do it on 'collectionViewCell:didSelectItem'. Then I run 'SKPaymentProcess'.

Comment: Did you test it from an IPv6 network?

Comment: I dont get what is iPv6 network and how to test it.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/support/ipv6/ - Of course, it may be nothing to do with IPv6, they are just telling you how they tested it.

Comment: I think my app supports ipv6. I use CloudKit to sync data and StoreKit to ask user for a review... and now it doesnt work for ipv6. There should be sth else...

Comment: @Paulw11 Even it doesnt work on ipv6, what should I do to fix it? Should I add sth to info.plist?

Comment: You misunderstand what they've said.  Just because it doesn't work on their iPad, that doesn't mean it works on the iPhone.  They just use the iPad to test all iOS submissions.  That 'IPv6 network' statement is a typical reason for rejecting an app, which doesn't necessarily describe the actual reason.  See the following topic.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554285/application-rejected-with-the-reason-of-lack-of-ipv6-support/42554803#42554803

Comment: First you need to reproduce the issue, then you can debug it. You can try just resubmitting if you really think it works on iPad.

Comment: @ElTomato so is it possible that it doesnt work? Or it is just "any reason" because of sth else? For me it works on every device;(

Comment: if you used AFNetworking please update that library